# How to assign value in variable in class using double pointer?

Tags: c++, tree

```
//Structure of Tree Data Structure

class node {

public:
    int    data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;


    void create_node(class node **, int);
};

void node::create_node(class node **newnode, int data)
{

    //class node *newnode;
    *newnode = (class node *)malloc(sizeof(class node));

    *(newnode)->data = data;//Assigning data to struct member
    *(newnode)->left = NULL;
    *(newnode)->right = NULL;
}

int main() {

    class node ob1, *newnode;
    ob1.create_node(&newnode, 1);
    //Printing values from class

    std::cout << "Root: " << newnode->data << '\n';
    std::cout << "Left: " << newnode->left << '\n';
    std::cout << "Right: " << newnode->right << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Please ask a question instad of just posting a code snipped. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question

Comment: `void node::create_node(class node **newnode, int data)` thats what constructors are for. You can't learn C++ by throwing what you learned to be C onto a C++-compiler.

Comment: `struct node *left;` ... `struct node` or `class node`? Pick \*one\*.

Comment: `*newnode = (class node *)malloc(sizeof(class node));` ... Who calls the constructor of `node`? Formally there is no object of type `node` untill the constuctor has run. Who `free()`s the memory (and calls the destructor before that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do it:

```
 (*newnode)->data = data;
 (*newnode)->left = nullptr;     
 (*newnode)->right = nullptr;
```

Notice the location of the asterisk in my answer and yours.

The -> operator is being called before the * operator in your version as it has higher precedence. So you are essentially trying to access an attribute of a pointer to an object and not the object itself.

Refer to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) for more information on which operators are called first.

Comment: Don't use `NULL` in modern C++-

Comment: @Swordfish Would be preferable to use?

Comment: `nullptr` should be used.